# Use preg_replace to Append a Value

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Assume i have the following hrefs:

> .... href="http://localhost/centboox/usedtextbooks/desc/30" ....

I would like to through all of them and add **** just before closing the href's double quotation:

```
... href="http://localhost/webname/pagename/desc/30*******" ...
```

Asterisks represent some input e.g. ?q=all&a=search_text

How can i do this via preg_replace in PHP.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you need `preg_replace`... you aren't replacing anything... just append to the string... Check out my answer below...

Comment: @JustinWood: The `****`s need to be *inserted* at a specific position in a longer string (see the `...`s around the example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace('/href="[^"]*/', '\0********', $subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't just concatenate if you're going to ALWAYS do it to the end of the string?

```
// Assuming you're array is already filled out...
$somethingToAppend = "?q=all&a=search_text"

foreach($hrefs as $key => $value) {
    $hrefs[$key] = $value + $somethingToAppend;
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example:

```
$href = <<<EOHTML
<a href="test.html?value=one">LINK</a>
EOHTML;

$href = preg_replace("/href=\"([^\"]*)\"/",
   "href=\"$1**\"", $href);

echo $href;
```

In the regex pattern I'm looking for `href="(something)"` and I'm replacing it with `href="(something)**"`.

Answer (score 0):

here is examples of preg_replace it may get useful to you. check below link

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php